# Problema com Redirect JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2.2

Estou com um Bean CDI Session o qual armazeno algumas informações para uso na aplicação enquanto o usuário estiver logado, porem eu preciso de um controle que quando os demais beans tentar utilizar algum atributo deste Bean ele estiver Null que o usuário seja redirecionado para a pagina de seleção da informação.

Fez a implementação no get do tributo em questão e valido se a pagina atual é a pagina da seleção se for ele abre a pagina se não ele redireciona. Esta solução funciona para algumas telas para outras apresenta erro 500 e sei que não é a forma ideal de tratar este problema.

Alguma sugestão de como posso fazer?

Answer (score 0):

O **OmniFaces** tem uma *feature* chamada `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`, que te redireciona para a página que você escolher se determinada `Exception` for criada.

Exemplo:

```
public String getBla() {
    if (bla == null) {
        throw new BlaException();
    }
    return bla;
}
```

Em `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>br.com.bla.BlaException</exception-type>
    <location>/bla.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Comment: Vou verificar e testar.

Comment: Creio que estou fazendo algo errado, mas não funcionou.
Implementei como o exemplo da documento mas ficou pedindo para lançar exception e não conseguir fazer funcionar.

Comment: Neste seu exemplo falou a classe BlaException, quando insiro ele no get do atributo ele pede pra fazer um Try ou lançar a exceção e não funciona.

Comment: Exato. Ou você cria a função `public String getBla() throws BlaException {` ou você provoca uma `RuntimeException`, assim: `throw new RuntimeException(new BlaException());`.